# how to publish the records of a Data Extension in an html table

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, ssjs, cloudpage, developer

I am using the following code to retrieve all the records of a data extension:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load('core', '1');

    var stagingDE = DataExtension.Init("4FB9D69F-A7EF-4811-A588-453832459D6F");
    var data = stagingDE.Rows.Retrieve();

    if (typeof(data) == 'object' && data.length > 0) {
      Write("The Value " + Stringify(data));
    } else {
      Write("No Rows Found");
    }
</script>
```

it shows them to me as follows:

```
The Value 
[{"ID_SEGMENTOSEG":"007","ID_CLIENTESEG":"32112.12","DNISEG":"321321","ACCOUNT_IDSEG":"DF6G5B65DFG1B56","MOSTRAR":"1","FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG":"4/4/2022 12:00:00 AM","IDKEYCLIENTESEG":"C123","FIRTSNAMESEG":"Jeff"},
 {"ID_SEGMENTOSEG":"007","ID_CLIENTESEG":"5515.22","DNISEG":"54564","ACCOUNT_IDSEG":"FDSFG14S5F1G6","MOSTRAR":"1","FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG":"7/6/2022 12:00:00 AM","IDKEYCLIENTESEG":"C312","FIRTSNAMESEG":"Pedro"}, 
{"ID_SEGMENTOSEG":"007","ID_CLIENTESEG":"2131.21","DNISEG":"13211","ACCOUNT_IDSEG":"SDDFSDF54654","MOSTRAR":"1","FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG":"12/13/2022 12:00:00 AM","IDKEYCLIENTESEG":"C987","FIRTSNAMESEG":"Hugo"}]
```

but I need to show them in an html table to make it look friendly in a cloud page, can someone help me how should be the code to show me the records of the data extension in an html table, thanks.

I am running the code without the value and it generates error 500, because each data extension is supposed to have different records so I should not put the value inside my code,
sorry if I'm saying a nonsense but it is the first time I use this language below the code as I'm writing it, could you tell me if I'm doing something wrong? thank you very much.

```javascript
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load('core', '1');

    var stagingDE = DataExtension.Init("4FB9D69F-A7EF-4811-A588-453832459D6F");
    var data = stagingDE.Rows.Retrieve();
  
  
     if (data.length > 0) {

      var jsonObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(data);

      for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++ ) {

          var seg = jsonObj[i];

          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@ID_SEGMENTOSEG", seg['ID_SEGMENTOSEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@ID_CLIENTESEG", seg['ID_CLIENTESEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@DNISEG", seg['DNISEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@ACCOUNT_IDSEG", seg['ACCOUNT_IDSEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG", seg['FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@IDKEYCLIENTESEG", seg['IDKEYCLIENTESEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@FIRTSNAMESEG", seg['FIRTSNAMESEG']);

          if (i == 0) {
            Write("<table border='1'>");
          }

          </script>

            
                %%=v(@ID_SEGMENTOSEG)=%%
                %%=v(@ID_CLIENTESEG)=%%
                %%=v(@DNISEG)=%%
                %%=v(@ACCOUNT_IDSEG)=%%
                %%=v(@FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG)=%%
                %%=v(@IDKEYCLIENTESEG)=%%
                %%=v(@FIRTSNAMESEG)=%%
            

          <script runat="server">

          if (i == jsonObj.length-1) {
            Write("</table>");
          }

      }  // for-loop     

    } else {
      Write("No Rows Found");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the columns, data types and data samples from your source Data Extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to parse the JSON *string* into an actual object and then loop through it.  Once you've got your loop working, you can break out of it and output the HTML.  Here's how I'd do it:

```javascript
<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load('core', '1');
    
    //var stagingDE = DataExtension.Init("4FB9D69F-A7EF-4811-A588-453832459D6F");
    //var data = stagingDE.Rows.Retrieve();
    var data = '[{"ID_SEGMENTOSEG":"007","ID_CLIENTESEG":"32112.12","DNISEG":"321321","ACCOUNT_IDSEG":"DF6G5B65DFG1B56","MOSTRAR":"1","FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG":"4/4/2022 12:00:00 AM","IDKEYCLIENTESEG":"C123","FIRTSNAMESEG":"Jeff"},{"ID_SEGMENTOSEG":"007","ID_CLIENTESEG":"5515.22","DNISEG":"54564","ACCOUNT_IDSEG":"FDSFG14S5F1G6","MOSTRAR":"1","FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG":"7/6/2022 12:00:00 AM","IDKEYCLIENTESEG":"C312","FIRTSNAMESEG":"Pedro"},{"ID_SEGMENTOSEG":"007","ID_CLIENTESEG":"2131.21","DNISEG":"13211","ACCOUNT_IDSEG":"SDDFSDF54654","MOSTRAR":"1","FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG":"12/13/2022 12:00:00 AM","IDKEYCLIENTESEG":"C987","FIRTSNAMESEG":"Hugo"}]'

    if (data.length > 0) {

      var jsonObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(data);

      for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++ ) {

          var seg = jsonObj[i];

          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@ID_SEGMENTOSEG", seg['ID_SEGMENTOSEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@ID_CLIENTESEG", seg['ID_CLIENTESEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@DNISEG", seg['DNISEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@ACCOUNT_IDSEG", seg['ACCOUNT_IDSEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@MOSTRAR", seg['MOSTRAR']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG", seg['FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@IDKEYCLIENTESEG", seg['IDKEYCLIENTESEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@FIRTSNAMESEG", seg['FIRTSNAMESEG']);

          if (i == 0) {
            Write("<table border='1'>");
          }

          </script>

            <tr>
                <td>%%=v(@ID_SEGMENTOSEG)=%%</td>
                <td>%%=v(@ID_CLIENTESEG)=%%</td>
                <td>%%=v(@DNISEG)=%%</td>
                <td>%%=v(@ACCOUNT_IDSEG)=%%</td>
                <td>%%=v(@MOSTRAR)=%%</td>
                <td>%%=v(@FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG)=%%</td>
                <td>%%=v(@IDKEYCLIENTESEG)=%%</td>
                <td>%%=v(@FIRTSNAMESEG)=%%</td>
            </tr>

          <script runat="server">

          if (i == jsonObj.length-1) {
            Write("</table>");
          }

      }  // for-loop     

    } else {
      Write("No Rows Found");
    }

</script>
```

Demo: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/gO6zKDVa

**EDIT**

Here's an updated version that better simulates the results from a [Rows.Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRetrieve.html).  My assumption is that there's a field in your source Data Extension named `data`.  I also added `field1` and `field2` as examples of other columns that may be in your Data Extension.

```javascript
<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load('core', '1');
    
    //var stagingDE = DataExtension.Init("4FB9D69F-A7EF-4811-A588-453832459D6F");
    //var stagingRow = stagingDE.Rows.Retrieve();
    var stagingRow = [{"data":"[{\"ID_SEGMENTOSEG\":\"007\",\"ID_CLIENTESEG\":\"32112.12\",\"DNISEG\":\"321321\",\"ACCOUNT_IDSEG\":\"DF6G5B65DFG1B56\",\"MOSTRAR\":\"1\",\"FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG\":\"4/4/2022 12:00:00 AM\",\"IDKEYCLIENTESEG\":\"C123\",\"FIRTSNAMESEG\":\"Jeff\"},{\"ID_SEGMENTOSEG\":\"007\",\"ID_CLIENTESEG\":\"5515.22\",\"DNISEG\":\"54564\",\"ACCOUNT_IDSEG\":\"FDSFG14S5F1G6\",\"MOSTRAR\":\"1\",\"FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG\":\"7/6/2022 12:00:00 AM\",\"IDKEYCLIENTESEG\":\"C312\",\"FIRTSNAMESEG\":\"Pedro\"},{\"ID_SEGMENTOSEG\":\"007\",\"ID_CLIENTESEG\":\"2131.21\",\"DNISEG\":\"13211\",\"ACCOUNT_IDSEG\":\"SDDFSDF54654\",\"MOSTRAR\":\"1\",\"FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG\":\"12/13/2022 12:00:00 AM\",\"IDKEYCLIENTESEG\":\"C987\",\"FIRTSNAMESEG\":\"Hugo\"}]","field1":"whee!","field2":"whoa!"}]

    var data = stagingRow[0].data;

    if (data && data.length > 0) {

      var jsonObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(data);

      for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++ ) {

          var seg = jsonObj[i];

          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@ID_SEGMENTOSEG", seg['ID_SEGMENTOSEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@ID_CLIENTESEG", seg['ID_CLIENTESEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@DNISEG", seg['DNISEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@ACCOUNT_IDSEG", seg['ACCOUNT_IDSEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@MOSTRAR", seg['MOSTRAR']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG", seg['FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@IDKEYCLIENTESEG", seg['IDKEYCLIENTESEG']);
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@FIRTSNAMESEG", seg['FIRTSNAMESEG']);

          if (i == 0) {
            Write("<table border='1'>");
          }

          </script>

          <tr>
              <td>%%=v(@ID_SEGMENTOSEG)=%%</td>
              <td>%%=v(@ID_CLIENTESEG)=%%</td>
              <td>%%=v(@DNISEG)=%%</td>
              <td>%%=v(@ACCOUNT_IDSEG)=%%</td>
              <td>%%=v(@MOSTRAR)=%%</td>
              <td>%%=v(@FECHA_NACIMIENTOSEG)=%%</td>
              <td>%%=v(@IDKEYCLIENTESEG)=%%</td>
              <td>%%=v(@FIRTSNAMESEG)=%%</td>
          </tr>

          <script runat="server">

          if (i == jsonObj.length-1) {
            Write("</table>");
          }


      }  // for-loop     

    } else {
      Write("No Rows Found");
    }


</script>
```

Demo: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/Q2yJE5WM

Comment: I am running the code without the value and it generates error 500, because each data extension is supposed to have different records so I should not put the value inside my code, 
sorry if I'm saying a nonsense but it is the first time I use this language below the code as I'm writing it, could you tell me if I'm doing something wrong? thank you very much.

Comment: Added another example that better illustrates what's returned from a Row.Retrieve.